# Pass data between pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on a mobile app on phonegap, and I need to pass variables between pages exactly like : http://coenraets.org/apps/directory/jqm/index.html

but my problem is that I can't use a php file.
How can I do that ? 
Thank you :)

I just tried the LocalStorage which is mentionned here : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage
but it doesn't work :
here's my code :

**Page1 :**

```
$(data).find("Book").each(function () {
        var temp = $(this).find("name").text();
        var temp1 = $("#champ").val().replace(" ", "") ;

        if (temp1 != "") {
            if (temp.toLowerCase().search(myRegExp) > -1) {
                $("#result_list").append("<li><a href='recherche_details.html' data-transition='pop'><img src='images/a.jpg' /><p><strong>Titre : " + temp + "</strong></p><p>Auteur : " + $(this).find("address").text() + "</p><p>Pays : " + $(this).find("country").text() + "</p></a></li>").listview("refresh") ;
                $envoi_search.attr("disabled", "");
                // Using the LocalStorage
                window.localStorage.setItem("titre" + i, temp);
                i++ ;
            }
        }
    });
```

**Page2 :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for Cordova to load
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // keyname is now equal to "key"
            var value = window.localStorage.getItem("titre0");
            $("#result").append("Yoooo" + value + " !! you are here") ;
        }
    </script>
```

but it doesn't work.
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You're going to have to use cookies in this case.

Comment: No, you said you can't use PHP. So an alternative is to store the variable in a cookie and retrieve it when you get to the next page.

Comment: ok thanks, I'm going to search on this way

Answer (score 1):

Set your variable in either the `location.hash` or `location.search` (querystring), then retrieve it using JavaScript on the second page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties

Don't forget that when you retrieve `location.hash` or `location.search`, you'll want to strip the first character (# or ?) using something like `.substring(1)`:

```
var hash = location.hash.substring(1);
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) for techniques to parse a `location.search` string into keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use LocalStorage for this, store the data in the first page and retrieve it in the next.

Then clear the localstorage to prevent it from being left behind.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage